# Clojure proxy of JComboBox and IDeref gives a java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, swing, clojure

Somewhere in my code, I do this:

```
(proxy [JComboBox IDeref] []
  (deref [] (.getSelectedItem this)))
```

While on my machine this works fine, some users reported the following problem:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class ggo.igs.gui.widgets.proxy$javax.swing.JComboBox$IDeref$db53459f 
  overrides final method 1®­+1ú h.1®ˆû1ú h
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (ClassLoader.java:-2)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:676)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:260)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:56)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:195)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:-2)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:188)
    com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass (JNLPClassLoader.java:332)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:317)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:252)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal (ClassLoader.java:375)
    ggo.igs.gui.widgets$combo_box.doInvoke (widgets.clj:124)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:440)
```

I don't see where I might override a final method, especially not with this weird "name".
Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with checking the JDK version on both environments (yours and your users): java.lang.VerifyError can be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is 1.6 on my and 1.5 on their computer - but isn't swing supposed to be compatible between these?

Comment: It should be binary compabtible, but I wouldn't bet my life on it ;) To be safe you could set your IDE to compile using a Java 5 JDK.